# sql to receive all information using count

Tags: sql

I have a table called products and has attributes code, type(tablet, desktop, phone), and manufacturer.

I want to get the information of the number of tablets each manufacturer makes.

```
select manufacturer, count(manufacturer) 
from products 
where type = "tablet" 
group by manufacturer
```

This query only returns the manufacturers which have at least a tablet. I would like to also print manufacturers which have 0 tablets.

For example: (manufacturer, type)

1. (Samsung, tablet)
2. (Apple, tablet)
3. (Dell, phone)
4. (Apple, tablet)

Then I wish to get

```
Samsung: 1
Apple: 2
Dell: 0
```

Comment: Why does your query have a self join?  Do you have a list of all manufacturers?

Comment: just edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select p.manufacturer, sum(case when p.type = 'tablet' then 1 else 0 end)
from products p
group by p.manufacturer
```

Answer (score 1):

in PostgreSQL notation:

```
select manufacturer, COUNT(*)filter(WHERE type = 'tablet')
from products
group by manufacturer
```